# Error in workflow file, no password supplied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, github-actions

I have setup a Github Action to run the tests of my Rails application, but I keep getting this error:

```
Run bundle exec rails db:prepare
rails aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

This is the workflow yml file:

```
name: CI
on: [push]
jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    services:
      db:
        image: postgres:11
        env:
          POSTGRES_USER: postgres
          POSTGRES_DB: bb_test
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
        ports: ['5432:5432']
      redis:
        image: redis
        ports: ['6379:6379']
        options: --entrypoint redis-server

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Install missing libs
        run: sudo apt-get -yqq install libpq-dev
      - name: Setup Ruby
        uses: actions/setup-ruby@v1
        with:
          ruby-version: 2.6.x
      - name: Install gems
        run: |
          bundle config path vendor/bundle
          bundle install --jobs 4 --retry 3
      - name: Setup Node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: 10.13.0
      - uses: borales/actions-yarn@v2.0.0
        with:
          cmd: install
      - name: Setup test database and run tests
        env:
          DATABASE_URL: postgres://postgres:@localhost:5432/bb_test
          REDIS_URL: redis://localhost:6379/0
          RAILS_ENV: test
          RAILS_MASTER_KEY: ${{ secrets.RAILS_MASTER_KEY }}
          POSTGRES_USER: postgres
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
        run: |
          bundle exec rails db:prepare
          bundle exec rails test
```

While the issue seems obvious, it looks like I have provide a password.
So what is wrong in my yml file?

Comment: Is your `config/database.yml` actually using `POSTGRES_PASSWORD`?

Comment: the `database.yml` is not in version control, so it is not pushed to Github.

Comment: So this is your problem.

Comment: Yep it was. I am always told to never add database.yml to version control, that's why this is confusing for me. Thanks!

Comment: if the `POSTGRES_PASSWORD` environmental variable is supplied under the `services` key, am wondering if there is any reason it is also duplicated in the `steps` key (name: Setup test database and run tests)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As we found out in the comment discussion, this was due to the fact that `database.yml` was not committed to the repository, and therefore leaving rails without the understanding of which database to use, and with what credentials.

The reason I am posting this answer here, is to share how we do commit `database.yml` to production, while still maintaining the necessary security guideline of "not having secrets committed to source control".

Since all of Rails configuration files support ERB, you can use it to define secrets using environment variables. For example:

```
password: <%= ENV['POSTGRES_PASSWORD'] %>
```

And, for completeness, this is our `database.yml` - which lets you simply define production credentials using a single `DATABASE_URL` variable, or leave the environment variable empty, and still have sensible defaults for development and test environments:

```
# config/database.yml
<%
  host = 'localhost'
  username = 'appname_user'
  password = 'dev_password_123'
  database = nil

  if ENV['DATABASE_URL']
    matches = ENV['DATABASE_URL'].match(/:\/\/(?<username>.+):(?<password>.+)@(?<host>.+)\/(?<database>.+)$/)
    if matches
      host     = matches[:host]
      username = matches[:username]
      password = matches[:password]
      database = matches[:database]
    end
  end
%>

pg: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  host: <%= host %>
  pool: 5
  username: <%= username %>
  password: <%= password %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: <%= database || 'appname_dev' %>

test: &test
  <<: *default
  database: <%= database || 'appname_test' %>

production:
  <<: *default
  database: <%= database || 'appname' %>
```

Comment: Thanks, great explanation!